# Remove class that added after function complete jquery

Tags: jquery

When I click on the button inside #slider-text the area expands to 100vw, 100vh.

I want that "body" in the back does not scroll when area expands, and when I click on the button (area back to normal) this possibility work again. How I can do this?

```
$('button').click(function(eryh){
$('#slider-text').toggleClass('fullscreen');
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another class for your body tag:

```
.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then toggle the class:

```
$('button').click(function(eryh){
  $('#slider-text').toggleClass('fullscreen');
  $("body").toggleClass("overflow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself some JavaScript by toggling a class in the `body` as well:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#slider-text').toggleClass('fullscreen');
    $("body").toggleClass('no-overflow');
});
```

Obviously you'd have to write a bit of CSS but that'd make the code more clean and readable.

You could even write some CSS like the following to make it even more clearer:

```
body.fullscreen {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider-text.fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('body, #slider-text').toggleClass('fullscreen');
});
```